# Charlieplexing Topology Question

Tags: charlieplexing

I'm sitting here with a pencil and paper trying to arrange a charlieplexed 5x8 LED matrix. I'm trying to arrange this in such a manner that no two lines cross each other. Without a guiding theorem of some sort, I keep isolating lines, that is, the line ends up completely surrounded in a box composed of it's neighbor lines.

I'm looking at this problem and thinking "Some mathematician must have already solved this". Nodes, matrices, edges...it just feels like a topology problem. Anyhow, I don't have the maths to solve it, at least not conclusively.

Anybody have any thoughts on this?

To head this off - yes, this would be simple with multiplexing. I need to charlieplex this.

Comment: have you read the wikipedia article on the subject? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlieplexing

Comment: Yes, exhaustively, and reviewed UziMonkey's stuff (which was very helpful at the beginning), and reviewed the Arduino forum stuff. There may be an obvious answer, but I am a bear of very little brain :)

Comment: At 5 pins or more, you cant draw a full charlieplexing circuit without crossing lines. Topology problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since most of the column lines are also row lines I doubt it 
is possible. To avoid crossing lines in a schematic I use
named nets.

My Charlie-plexing schematics (which use named nets) are at -- 
http://wiblocks.luciani.org/FAQ/faq-charlie-plex.html

Comment: Yeah, that's the conclusion I've reached, too.

Answer (score 3):

I am unclear what you mean by "no two lines cross each other". Is this just a problem with the display of the schematic? If so, it's quite common for un-connected lines to cross on a schematic. Often you will see connected lines have a little filled circle 'joint' to indicate the connect, and unconnected lines, one of the lines will make a little unfilled half-circle 'jump' over the other line, to indicate they are crossing but not connected.

Comment: Yeah, I know they CAN cross, but I'm trying like the devil to avoid that.

Comment: @Chris - It's far better to have a logically organized schematic than one which has no crossing lines, or one which mimics the layout too closely.  Usually, the goal is to have current flowing from left to right, with high voltages at the top and lower ones at the bottom.  I understand that this is next to impossible with a Charlieplexed circuit,  but jluciani's method isn't bad. See tc3.iec.ch/pdf_files/pdf_tc3/3_594.pdf

Answer (score 1):

A "Charlieplexed" display (Wikipedia lists the concept as having been invented in 1996, but I'm sure the approach was used before that) represents a complete graph of all processor signals (every pair of processor signals has to have an LED on it).  A complete planar graph of N nodes may only be drawn for N less than 4.

I think the most natural way to visualize a Charlieplexed display would be as a square matrix with the LED's on the primary diagonal replaced with shorting jumpers.  When laying out a board, simply shove the LEDs on either side of the diagonal inward so as to yield an NxN-1 physical configuration.

The only disadvantages Charlieplexing would have over normal multiplexing would be the fact that Charlieplexing uses a nearly-square square grid, and that one has to in software shift the pixels on one side of the diagonal so as to account for the gap.  Electrically, I would think driving a Charlieplexed display from a tri-state CPU pin should be easy: wire an NPN transistor (e.g. 2N2222) with the collector at VDD, base connected to the CPU pin, and the emitter tied to the Charlieplex line to supply the positive (row-scanned) drive; wire a current-setting resistor between the CPU pin and the column wire.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better formulation of this question is:

Can the schematic of an n-channel charlieplexed circuit be drawn as a finite, connected planar graph?

Euler's formula could probably be used in some way (it's a planar graph if vertices − edges + faces = 2), but you'd need a nice clean formula (well, maybe a messy one would work too) for determining the number of faces in the graph.